# Proving size of two finite sets is equal to the size of their union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am struggling to understand how to prove the following for ALL numbers.

```
Show that if S₁ and S₂ are finite sets with |S₁| = n and |S₂| = m, then |S₁ U S₂| <= n + m.
```

It is easy for me to show this by creating two finite sets and going through the computations, but I am struggling to understand how to show this in general terms, or for ALL numbers.

Here is how I show it with sets that I created.

```
S₁= {1, 4, 5, 7}
|S₁| = 4 
S₂ = {4, 6, 8}
|S₂| = 3
S₁ ∪ S₂  = {1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
|S₁ ∪ S₂| = 6
6 <= (4 + 3)
6 <= 7
```

I am not seeing how to translate this to general terms.

Comment: Name  the  elements  of  $S_{1}$  as  $\{a_{1},a_{2},.....a_{n}\}$  and  those  of  $S_{2}$  as  $\{b_{1},b_{2}.......b_{m}\}$ . Now  look  at  the  union  having  two  cases  in  mind   - $1$) they  are  all  distinct, $2$)Some  elements  are  repeated.  Start  writing , probably  you  will  get  there  by  yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard theorem (see, e.g. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Union_and_intersection)), that $$|S_1|+|S_2|=|S_1\cup S_2|+|S_1\cap S_2|$$

We rearrange as $$|S_1\cup S_2|=|S_1|+|S_2|-|S_1\cap S_2|\le |S_1|+|S_2|$$

Comment: Can you please explain where the <= came from @vadim123? I am not seeing that.

Comment: Because $-|S_1\cap S_2|\le 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** We can induct on $|S_1|$ (with $|S_2|$ fixed) and use $|X\setminus\{x\}|+1=|X|$ for any $x\in X$ (i.e. $|X\cup\{x\}|=|X|+1$ when $x\notin X$).

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it by induction
by using this fundamental theorem
on unions:

$|S \cup x|
= |S| \text{ if }\ x \in S;
 |S|+1
\text{ if } x \not\in S
$.

In particular,
this implies that
$|S \cup x|
\le |S|+1
$.